# CORS vs Autofac vs Exception handling middleware in Owin, which one goes first?

Tags: owin, autofac, startup, owin-middleware

I have an owin setup that among many other things, uses CORS and Autofac.
The Autofac documentation says "Register the Autofac middleware FIRST.", many people say app.UseCors should be the very first thing.

I also have an exception handling middleware, which many people also say should be the first thing so that "other middlewares (down the stacktrace) will propagate up and be caught by the try/catch block of this middleware.", and this one makes a lot of sense, since the implementation looks like:

```
        try
        {
            await Next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch...
```

which one should be first?
what is the correct order for these 3 middleware components

my current Startup Configuration looks like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        // Add WebApi CORS handling to the OWIN pipeline
        app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // Create and register Owin HttpConfig instance
        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always // Enable error details in http responses
        };

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST. This also adds Autofac-injected middleware
        // registered with the container.
        var container = AutofacConfig.ConfigureContainer(config);
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);

        app.UseNLog();

        // Handle exceptions from OWIN middleware components globally
        app.UseExceptionHandling();

        app.UseOAuth(config);
        //... quite a bit more stuff after
```

Answer (score 0):

I think when the documentation says "Register the Autofac middleware FIRST" it is in the context of stating the right order between the following three components: 1) Autofac middleware, 2) Autofac Web API middleware, and 3) the standard Web API middleware.

CORS is not a part of this list, and it should be configured first: you have to call `.UseCors` before calling  `.UseWebApi`, or any other middleware that uses requests. Any request managed by any middleware should include the CORS Access-Control headers, otherwise you may get cross-origin access errors. I guess this applies also to your error handling middleware. So it should be configured after CORS (but before the other middleware components, if you want to handle their exceptions).

More info about CORS and Web API in [this page](http://datawalke.com/c/webapi-owin-cors-and-custom-headers/). More info about CORS details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

In fact the exact Autofac documentation comment says exactly "Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware, and finally the standard Web API middleware". In the code example in that documentation they have the standard web api setup code, and after that the OWIN web api setup (which is the section where this "First" applies).

```
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

    // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
    // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
    var config = new HttpConfiguration();

    // Register your Web API controllers.
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

    // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
    // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
    // to be Autofac.
    var container = builder.Build();
    config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

    // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
    // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
    app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
  }
}
```

The doc page where I got the code example is [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration) (I guess it is the same you checked).